# SQLite3 Update a row based on a select query in another table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sqlite

Basically I am trying to find a way to update the vehicle's booking status associated with the client_drivers_license_number after its matched to a variable I will input on my laravel project (123456789 below). I am not sure how I can make an update with values matching from mulitple tables so my best attempt is below so I can explain the idea of what I want to do. This is all in sqlite3.

```
UPDATE SET vehicle.is_booked = 0
FROM booking, vehicle
WHERE booking.vehicle_rego = vehicle.rego and booking.client_drivers_license_number = 123456789;
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this using `exists`:

```
UPDATE vehicle
    SET is_booked = 0
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM booking b
                  WHERE b.vehicle_rego = vehicle.rego AND  
                        b.client_drivers_license_number = 123456789
                 );
```

It seems odd that you would set `is_booked = 0` when a `booking` is available.  But then again, it seems odd that there are no date or times in this query at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am a total beginner with SQL so some of my stuff may seem weird but my thoughts behind is_booked is just to make it a binary value with 0 = false and 1 = true aka is_booked = 0 means the vehicle is available.